# LibGdx - How draw BitmapFontCache scaled?

Tags: fonts, libgdx, textures

If you are using FreeTypeFontGenerator or just a plain BitmapFont, you will want to eventually employ BitmapFontCache. YET, BitmapFontCache does not provide a scaled draw method. 
So, how do you draw a bitmap to the screen with changing scale? I tried drawing to texture, but it's not very clear how can this be done ...

Answer (score 1):

So, the fast can be to check the scale, if it is some constant (1.0 is the default) use the drawing cache, and when needed use BitmapFont's **getData().setScale()** method as so:

```
@Override
public void draw( Batch batch, float parentAlpha )
{
    try
    {
        super.draw( batch, parentAlpha );
        if( getScaleX() != 1 || getScaleY() != 1 )
        {
            mCache.getFont().getData().setScale( getScaleX(), getScaleY() );
            mCache.getFont().draw( batch, text(), mTextX, mTextY );
        }
        else
        {
            mCache.setPosition( mTextX, mTextY );
            mCache.draw( batch );
        }
    }
    catch( Throwable t )
    {
        Gdx.app.error( tag, "write() - Exception: " + t.getMessage(), t );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for catching all Throwables? Very dangerous coding practice.

Comment: Very simple... to catch all exceptions, so the log shows the errors and the app doesn't crash... Best Practice in my opinion